# How to create a nested Map using Collectors.groupingBy?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have a list of class say `ProductDto`

```
public class ProductDto {
    private String Id;
    private String status;
    private Booker booker;
    private String category;
    private String type;
}
```

I want to have a Map as below:-

`Map<String,Map<String,Map<String,Booker>>`

The properties are to be mapped as below:

`Map<status,Map<category,Map<type,Booker>`

I know one level of grouping could be done easily without any hassles using `Collectors.groupingBy`.

I tried to use this for nested level but it failed for me when same values  started coming for fields that are keys.

My code is something like below:-

```
 list.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                        (FenergoProductDto productDto) -> 
                        productDto.getStatus()
                        ,
                        Collectors.toMap(k -> k.getProductCategory(), fProductDto -> {
                            Map<String, Booker> productTypeMap = new ProductTypes();
                            productTypeMap.put(fProductDto.getProductTypeName(),
                                    createBooker(fProductDto.getBookingEntityName()));
                            return productTypeMap;
                        })
                ));
```

If anyone knows a good approach to do this by using streams, please share!

Comment: You need to give a reducingfunction indicating what needs to be done in case of key conflicts

Comment: Can you please post here something working or any reference links etc?

Comment: nested groupingBy questions and solutions:

Answer (score 26, accepted):

### Abstract / Brief discussion

Having a map of maps of maps is questionable when seen from an object-oriented prespective, as it might seem that you're lacking some abstraction (i.e. you could create a class `Result` that encapsulates the results of the nested grouping). However, it's perfectly reasonable when considered exclusively from a pure data-oriented approach.

So here I present two approaches: the first one is purely data-oriented (with nested `groupingBy` calls, hence nested maps), while the second one is more OO-friendly and makes a better job at abstracting the grouping criteria. Just pick the one which better represents your intentions and coding standards/traditions and, more importantly, the one you most like.

---

### Data-oriented approach

For the first approach, you can just nest the `groupingBy` calls:

```
Map<String, Map<String, Map<String, List<Booker>>>> result = list.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(ProductDto::getStatus,
             Collectors.groupingBy(ProductDto::getCategory,
             Collectors.groupingBy(ProductDto::getType,
                 Collectors.mapping(
                         ProductDto::getBooker,
                         Collectors.toList())))));
```

As you see, the result is a `Map<String, Map<String, Map<String, List<Booker>>>>`. This is because there might be more than one `ProductDto` instance with the same `(status, category, type)` combination.

Also, as you need `Booker` instances instead of `ProductDto` instances, I'm *adapting* the last `groupingBy` collector so that it returns `Booker`s instead of `productDto`s.

---

#### About *reduction*

If you need to have only one `Booker` instance instead of a `List<Booker>` as the value of the innermost map, you would need a way to *reduce* `Booker` instances, i.e. convert many instances into one by means of an associative operation (accumulating the sum of some attribute being the most common one).

---

### Object-oriented friendly approach

For the second approach, having a `Map<String, Map<String, Map<String, List<Booker>>>>` might be seen as bad practice or even as pure evil. So, instead of having a map of maps of maps of lists, you could have only one map of lists whose keys represent the combination of the 3 properties you want to group by.

The easiest way to do this is to use a `List` as the key, as lists already provide `hashCode` and `equals` implementations:

```
Map<List<String>, List<Booker>> result = list.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
         dto -> Arrays.asList(dto.getStatus(), dto.getCategory(), dto.getType()),
         Collectors.mapping(
                 ProductDto::getBooker,
                 Collectors.toList())))));
```

If you are on Java 9+, you can use [`List.of`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/List.html#of-E-E-E-) instead of `Arrays.asList`, as `List.of` returns a fully immutable and highly optimized list.

Comment: Awesome! Great  answer :) Alternatives are welcome too :)

Comment: Just one quick doubt! Suppose ProductDto::getBooker has 3 properties a,b and c And we need to populate these properties rather than collecting these into a list. How could that be achieved?

Comment: If I ever see a map of map of maps, I git blame and glare at whoever's responsible.

Comment: @VinayPrajapati I would need more background to answer that... I thought `Booker` was an instance of `ProductDto`. But in your comment you are talking about a *side-effect* (setting properties). So I'd ask why you are grouping then. If you need both grouping and setting the attributes, then I'd first group and then modify the `Booker` instances, once they are grouped. Remember that you'd also need to reduce the list of `Booker`s by some mean.

Comment: @Michael nested maps are perfecly legitimate in specific cases. in our company we use multi-level maps in order to implement fast access and low memory footprint data projections

Comment: @epol I didn't say all nested maps. I said 3 (or more) levels. They are too hard to reason about and unwieldy to use, especially when the keys are the same types. There's rarely a performance justification for writing something unreadable. When maintaining multiple indices, there's almost always a better strategy than going crazy with maps. cqengine is a good one

Answer (score 1):

nested groupingBy questions and solutions:
q. print all male and female  dept-wise(nested groupingBy):
ans:

```
employeeList.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Employee::getDepartment,Collectors.groupingBy(Employee::getGender)))
        .entrySet().stream().forEach(System.out::println)
```

q. print the employees more than 25 and not -  male and female - dept-wise
ans:

```
employeeList.stream().collect(
Collectors.groupingBy(Employee::getDepartment, Collectors.groupingBy(Employee::getGender, Collectors.partitioningBy(emp -> emp.getAge() > 25))))
.entrySet().stream().forEach(System.out::println);
```

q. eldest male and female from each department
ans:

```
employeeList.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Employee::getDepartment,Collectors.groupingBy(Employee::getGender,Collectors.maxBy(Comparator.comparing(Employee::getAge)))))
        .entrySet().stream().forEach(System.out::println);
```

some more helpful questions @:
[1]: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AFmyV43UBgc